# What is a word for something that occupies one's entire field of vision?

Tags: single-word-requests

Trying to describe a grand building, like nothing ever seen before. When you stand at the bottom of the staircase, all you can see is the staircase, it occupies your entire field of vision.

How might I describe this staircase at that moment?

*The **[word]** marble staircase towers before you, presenting its perfection.*

Comment: The looming marble staircase ...  *looming* 2a : to appear in an impressively great or exaggerated form  - Merriam Webster.

Comment: @Jim..I feel looming should be used in a negative situation .E.g: The looming water crisis ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Panoramic**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/panoramic) is the first thing that comes to mind:

> with a view of a wide area:
>
> *a wonderful panoramic view of the countryside*
>    *She used a panoramic camera and long exposures to capture
>    the effects of fading light.*

Comment: A panoramic staircase? Probably in Niagara Falls!

Comment: Oh wow, that perfectly fits what I had in mind. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the staircase filling your entire field of vision, it is, for you at that moment, no matter where you look, [**omnipresent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnipresent):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : present in all places at all times
>   // the museum's *omnipresent* security apparatus

Of course, this is relative. Nothing will *always* occupy your entire field of vision. Distance, in terms of both location and time, will make an objective difference.

But while you're present at the staircase:

> The *omnipresent* marble staircase towers before you, presenting its perfection.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

*The **dominate** marble staircase towers before you, presenting its perfection.*

[OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dominant) adj.

> more important, powerful or noticeable than other things